# How to build an AI Chatbot from scratch using NLTK?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I'm building an AI-based Q&A chatbot. What are the precise steps? How should I start working on it as I'm new to Python as well as AI. 
(Note:- Using Python and building a generative chatbot is mandatory as it's an assignment)

Comment: First of all you should do a proper research and build a plan to start with...

Comment: You will easily find a blog or an article on this topic if you google properly. First write down the steps that you think needs to be followed and then compare it woth the resources you find.

Answer (score 0):

Chatbots, well at least the ones worth naming chatbots, are quite intricate. There are lots of teams out there working every day to make one. But, the good news is that the word "intelligent" doesn't have an exact definition and something simple will probably suffice for you.

You can use an exact matching method which will let you down the first time you give it a chance. You can compare the set of words in existing questions and the one you receive, which is a little bit better. But, If you still feel you want to push it further, read this:

[How to Create a Simple JARVIS — Chatbots are Coming](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-to-create-a-simple-jarvis-chatbots-are-coming-b2cd9238376e)

I hope that helps.